# How do I set the riskCheck parameter in my Twilio API call using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, twilio-api

We have been using this code to send SMS messages from a Google Sheet, using Google Apps Script and Twilio API:

```
function sendSms(message) {
  const number = "+44########";
  var twilioAccountSID = "###############################";
  var twilioAuthToken = "#################################";
  var messages_url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/" + twilioAccountSID + "/Messages.json";

  var payload = {
    "To": number,
    "Body" : message,
    "From" : "+44#########"  //Twilio number
  };

  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload
  };

  options.headers = { 
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(twilioAccountSID + ':' + twilioAuthToken)
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(messages_url, options);
}
```

We have started getting errors with code 30450, a possible solution Twilio offer is:

*...you can use the optional RiskCheck parameter when creating a Message
with the Programmable Messaging API. To prevent a known/legitimate message from getting blocked in future by SMS Pumping Protection, include the RiskCheck parameter with value disable when creating the new Message resource.*

Does anyone know how I can add this RiskCheck parameter to my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have a Twilio account to test it, but according to their [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/api/message-resource) you need to add `riskCheck` to your payload:

```js
var payload = {
  "To": number,
  "Body" : message,
  "From" : "+44#########",
  "riskCheck": "disable"
};
```

Comment: OK, thanks, I wondered if it was that but because the other parameters in the payload started with a capital letter and this one with a lowercase, I thought it couldn't be right!

Comment: @SJO I think other params shouldn't start with a capital letter as well. However, if it works, they are likely to be case-insensitive. Once you test it and if it works, could mark the question answered, please.

Comment: It doesn't give an error, so I'm presuming it works!  Thanks.  However the SMS message still doesn't get sent so I'm now trying to add the phone number to Global Safe List via Global Safe List API, do you know anything about that?

Comment: @SJO I have not worked with Twilio's Global Safe List, only looked through the [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/global-safe-list).